# My profile won't load!

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, user-profile

I can get into my Windows Server 2008 R2 primary domain controller via remote desktop just fine.  It's my boss who's got his profile messed up.  When he tries to log in, he gets the message

> The User Profile service failed the
>   logon.
>   User profile cannot be loaded.

I've looked for his profile everywhere and cannot find it to delete or fix it.  System Properties > Advanced > User Profiles shows my profile, the Administrator profile and the Default Profile. HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList only shows my profile and the Administrator profile.  Everything that I've found on the internets points me to those locations.

Help a brotha out?

Answer (score 1):

Has he got a roaming redirected profile setup, in the past i have found the most common cause of this is a disk running out of space as roaming profile is loaded onto the local machine

Answer (score 1):

Please check the event log for related messages at the time your boss tries to log on.